# There are tunnels in PC. I was unable to know how and why they are there?

Tags: windows-7, tunnel, ipconfig

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret the output of ipconfig/all?](https://superuser.com/questions/308425/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-ipconfig-all)

`ipconfig /all` in my Windows-7 machine shows:

```
     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 22-24-2C-7F-A7-2E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 802.11b/g/n WiFi
Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-24-2C-4D-A7-AE
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8168D/8111D Family PCI-E Gigab
it Ethernet NIC (NDIS 6.20)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-23-8B-AC-3D-11
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E56DCCB4-5812-48C7-A4A9-E825E296AECE}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

In other computers which I had to work with had only two of them, normally Wi-Fi and Ethernet. Now there are more, I do not know what they are doing here. I sometimes use remote desktop connection to connect to my work PC from home. Once I had XAMPP installed in it but now I have uninstalled it. I do use [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/).

Is this the problem? or there is some other thing I have to worry about. I am worried about my files security as well as work files.

Note: I use internet which has a WEP security via Wi-Fi, this actually belongs to a neighbor and we share it. 
please let me know if it is a too little or too much information to resolve problem? I would be happy to add more info if needed.

Comment: This is not a problem, you don't need to worry.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: [How to interpret the output of ipconfig/all?](http://superuser.com/questions/308425/how-to-interpret-the-output-of-ipconfig-all)

Comment: @DaveRook     Thanks for quick response, I have edited the question as I missed some of the networks in earlier version.

Comment: You have different types like this, as you have IP4 and IP6 - I would guess from your stats, you don't use IP6

Comment: More reading about one of the adapters here http://superuser.com/questions/22290/what-is-the-teredo-tunneling-pseudo-interface. I'm not going to suggest any more, as I can easily find the answers by Googling or searching here on Super User